# Resize images to specific width only (AppleScript or Automator)

Tags: image, macos, applescript, image-resizing, automator

I've been searching google.com a couple of hours trying to find a way to do this, but there is no answer. Everywhere is resize to the longest size, but nothing about resize to the specified width only.

Is there any way in Automator or AppleScript to resize images to a specified width only, instead of just the longest size? I need my output images to be a specific width ony (e.g 200px).

Comment: You mean resize to a specified width, maintaining the aspect ratio, right?

Comment: This can be done using Applescript with Photoshop. Do you have Photoshop?

Comment: @NGAFD Yes I do. But I prefer not to use for this task this monster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with plain AppleScript and a shell utility entitled **sips**:

```
    on open droppings
    repeat with everyDrop in droppings
        set originalFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (everyDrop as text)
        tell application "Finder"
            set originalName to everyDrop's name
            set imageContainer to (everyDrop's container as text)
        end tell

        set reSizedName to "200W" & originalName
        set outputPath to quoted form of POSIX path of (imageContainer & reSizedName)

        do shell script "sips --resampleWidth 200 " & originalFile & " --out " & outputPath
    end repeat
end open

on run
    display dialog "Drop some Image Files to Re-size them all to 200 pixels wide" buttons {"Aye Aye"} default button "Aye Aye"
end run
```

This preserves the aspect ratio of the original image, and simply re-sizes the width to 200 pixels.  Hopefully you can see where you can make the changes necessary for your own workflow.

If you want to drop a folder of images as well as individual files, try this as a droplet:

```
on open droppings
    repeat with everyDrop in droppings
        if (info for everyDrop)'s folder is true then
            tell application "Finder" to set allImageFiles to everyDrop's every file
            repeat with eachFile in allImageFiles
                my SetWidthTo200(eachFile)
            end repeat
        else
            my SetWidthTo200(everyDrop)
        end if
    end repeat
end open

to SetWidthTo200(img)
    set originalFile to quoted form of POSIX path of (img as text)
    tell application "Finder"
        set originalName to img's name
        set imageContainer to (img's container as text)
    end tell
    set reSizedName to "200W" & originalName
    set outputPath to quoted form of POSIX path of (imageContainer & reSizedName)
    do shell script "sips --resampleWidth 200 " & originalFile & " --out " & outputPath
end SetWidthTo200


on run
    display dialog "Drop some Image Files to Re-size them all to 200 pixels wide" buttons {"Aye Aye"} default button "Aye Aye"
end run
```

There is still no error-checking or checking to be sure that the files are indeed image files, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Do you know how to adapt this so it works on multiple files that you just drop onto the script to make it more useful?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Quickest way is to use Script Editor's "Recursive Image File Processing Droplet" (see menu "File") where one could put the processing part of this code in the "process_item(this_item)" part.

Comment: @Zero Many thanks, I am looking at your suggestion right now.

Comment: :) @MarkSetchell => it has already a processing example using "Image Events" and here it is used to log the resolution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962969/applescript-droplet-export-image-resolution-of-all-files-in-folder-subfolder-a/27018922#27018922

Comment: I have edited the code to function as a droplet.  The script referred to by @Zero uses Image Events, which also uses **sips**, but does not provide its full functionality.  There is better error checking, though, and my script will choke if you drop a non-image file on it.

Comment: @CraigSmith If you know why it's not understand a folder, when I drop a folder it throw me an error [link](http://dsh.re/5d6de)?

Comment: Try the second script

Answer (score 0):

Here's a summary from this [OSX Tips](http://www.macgasm.net/2014/12/18/31-days-of-os-x-tips-use-automator-to-resize-multiple-images-at-once/) using automator to resize images

- open "Automator"
- File > New > Service
- Settings:

  - Service received selected: "image files"
  - in "Finder"
- in the left pane, find for action named "Get Selected Finder Items"
- Next look for action "Scale Images"
- If you wish to replace original, choose "Don’t Add" when it ask 
  "would you like to add a Copy Finder Items action", otherwise, choose add
- In order to be able to choose the highest pixels before scaling, click on Options at the right of results, tick 
  "show this action when the workflow run"

Comment: This scales images by their longest side, which does not solve the problem.